# Use Amazon Web Services to regularly hit a web page & email me if its down

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to use Amazon Web Services to regularly hit a web page & email me if its down.

I have researched this in Google but I can't find anything - also their list of services doesn't really seem to cover it. However we are using 1 or 2 of their other services and it would be ideal and reliable if they offered this.

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this on AWS by defining a [Route53 Health Check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-monitor-view-status.html).

AWS customers can also use [NewRelic standard services for free](http://newrelic.com/offers), which includes the ability to monitor a webpage like you are describing.

Of course there are tons of other services out there that perform this function as well, such as [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/).

Comment: Thanks - pingdom is what I'm using now but perhaps it's not as reliable as Route53 Health Check?

Comment: I'm actually using all three services I listed, and I get the same alerts at the same time from all 3. They are all basically doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The Route53 Health Check allows you to create an alarm which publishes a message to an SNS topic. The topic can be watched with email/webhook subscriptions that send an email or initiate an HTTP/HTTPS request with alarm details.

Here's a [guide](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/aws/route53-email-notifications/) on how to configure a Route53 email or Slack alert.

> The advanced integration that supports availability portals and statistics has a dependency on Axibase Time Series Database (my affiliation).

Sample alarm JSON (anonymized):

```
{
    "Type": "Notification",
    "MessageId": "NNN",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:route53_alert",
    "Subject": "ALARM: \"route53-alarm\" in US East (N. Virginia)",
    "Message": "{\"AlarmName\":\"route53-alarm\",\"AlarmDescription\":null,\"AWSAccountId\":\"111111111111\",\"NewStateValue\":\"ALARM\",\"NewStateReason\":\"Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [0.0 (20/03/18 16:17:00)] was less than the threshold (1.0).\",\"StateChangeTime\":\"2018-03-20T16:18:24.513+0000\",\"Region\":\"US East (N. Virginia)\",\"OldStateValue\":\"OK\",\"Trigger\":{\"MetricName\":\"HealthCheckStatus\",\"Namespace\":\"AWS/Route53\",\"StatisticType\":\"Statistic\",\"Statistic\":\"MINIMUM\",\"Unit\":null,\"Dimensions\":[{\"name\":\"HealthCheckId\",\"value\":\"726bed8e-c205-47d7-9d26-f8e61799b1a3\"}],\"Period\":60,\"EvaluationPeriods\":1,\"ComparisonOperator\":\"LessThanThreshold\",\"Threshold\":1.0,\"TreatMissingData\":\"\",\"EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile\":\"\"}}",
    "Timestamp": "2018-03-20T16:18:24.541Z",
    "SignatureVersion": "1",
    "Signature": "NNN",
    "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-NNN.pem",
    "UnsubscribeURL": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:route53_alert:NNN"
}
```